# Can`pip wheel` command create *universal* wheels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setup.py, python-wheel

**Is there a way to use the `pip wheel` command to create *universal* wheels?**

For instance, taking `aws_requests_auth` as an example, if I execute
`pip wheel aws_requests_auth,` a Python3 wheel is created: `aws_requests_auth-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl`.

Can I change something to create a `py2.py3-none-any.whl` wheel?

Files used in the above example:

```
$ ls -R
.:
aws_requests_auth  CHANGELOG.md  dist  LICENSE  MANIFEST  MANIFEST.in  PKG-INFO  README.md  setup.py

./aws_requests_auth:
aws_auth.py                               boto_utils.py                           chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl  __init__.py                           tests
aws_requests_auth-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl  certifi-2018.4.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl  idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl       requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl  urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl

./aws_requests_auth/tests:
__init__.py  test_aws_auth.py  test_boto_utils.py

./dist:
aws-requests-auth-0.4.1.tar.gz

$ cat setup.py 
from distutils.core import setup


setup(
    name='aws-requests-auth',
    version='0.4.1',
    author='David Muller',
    author_email='davehmuller@gmail.com',
    packages=['aws_requests_auth'],
    url='https://github.com/davidmuller/aws-requests-auth',
    description='AWS signature version 4 signing process for the python requests module',
    long_description='See https://github.com/davidmuller/aws-requests-auth for installation and usage instructions.',
    install_requires=['requests>=0.14.0'],
    classifiers=[
        'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
    ]
)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `--universal`, as explained in [the docs](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#defining-the-python-version)?

Comment: Yes, @abarnert, I tried `$ pip wheel --universal --wheel-dir=aws-requests-auth-0.4.1 Unidecode,` and `pip` complains: `no such option: --universal,` as I think the `--universal` argument is for commands other than pip.

Answer (score 1):

In `setup.cfg`:

```
[bdist_wheel]
universal=1
```

Refs: https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide.html#building-wheels